# TopoJSON arcs is undefined, coordinates is undefined, o is undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, d3.js, geojson, topojson

I am very new to d3 and topojson and I am trying to render a map of the UK to overlay some data onto later. I have taken a topojson file from an [online repository](https://github.com/deldersveld/topojson/blob/master/countries/united-kingdom/uk-counties.json) which is clearly fine since GitHub can render it. I am running this in a view specific json file for rails with d3 and topojson installed using webpacker.

I am currently importing d3, topojson and the uk map json file:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as topojson from 'topojson';
import * as uk from './uk.json';
```

Then I try to draw the map:

```
let svg = d3.select('#geo-plot');
let feature = topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.GBR_adm2);
svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(feature)
        .join("path")
        .attr("fill", "#ed87c8")
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .attr("stroke-width", 0.4)
        .attr("d", d3.geoPath(d3.geoMercator()));
```

I get the error `arcs is undefined` while running `topology.feature(...)`

If I pass `uk.objects.GBR_adm2.geometries` to `feature` is of type Feature but has no geometries.

I have a degree of success when passing `uk.objects.GBR_adm2.geometries` to `.data()` directly but I get the error `coordinates is undefined`.

If I pass `uk.objects.GBR_adm2` or `uk.objects` to `.data()`, nothing happens and I get no error.

I have tried all of these steps with [another map](https://github.com/deldersveld/topojson/blob/master/countries/united-states/lower-quality-20m/20m-US-congressional-districts-2015.json) and had the exact same outcome

I am trying to follow online tutorials but nobody seems to be running into these problems. Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I was able to draw the map using your code in a snippet in the answer box (using d3.json to load the data and <script src=" for the libraries), but to do so I had to pass .data() an array, either feature.features or [feature]. Otherwise, your issue appears to be related to how you are packing the code, not how you are using topojson.js.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. It makes sense that its a packing issue. I just cannot for the life of me figure out what. I have converted to geoJSON and that at least works, even if the file is bigger. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: The `feature` variable is a `FeatureCollection`, since `GBR_adm2` is a geometry collection in the original file. In order to see them as individual SVG elements, you need to pass `feature.features` as argument to the `data` method.